# jupyter notebook access issue in Chromium

Tags: permissions, chromium, jupyter

I'm getting a common error, but the `chmod` solutions I've found don't seem to be working.

When I create a Jupyter notebook through terminal, by running `jupyter notebook`,  on Ubuntu 19.10, I get this error I'm sure many are familiar with:

```
The file at file:///home/vurnhat/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-25715-open.html is not readable. It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

I've manually pasted the link into Firefox and it works. Is there any way I can change some setting in my Chromium browser to get it to work there?

Comment: which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Using Ubuntu 20.04 Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I don't know what the problem is with Chrome, but a quick "fix" for me was to run:

```
jupyter notebook --browser firefox
```

so I don't have to copy-paste the link in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is chromium being a snap app in Ubuntu, if the URL is used instead of the html file, the issue is resolved.
`jupyter notebook --generate-config`
will output the directory for config file, edit it and add this line
`c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False`

Answer (score 2):

Generate a jupyter config file in terminal using commands:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

open the script *jupyter_notebook_config.py* in the directory
*/.jupyter*  and uncomment the line 531 :
Set `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = True`
to
`c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False`.
It will work.

Comment: Thanks Suman, this solved the issue for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably be related to Chromium being a snap app. According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61542904/3140225):

> With recent versions of snap, applications installed with snap can't
> by default open files in hidden folders (with a name starting by `.`).
>
> In Ubuntu 20.04, chromium is installed with snap (even when using the
> command `sudo apt install chromium-browser`), so chromium can't open
> the html file used by Jupyter.
>
> As stated by @rahul-sood, a simple workaround is to copy-paste one of
> the alternative links given by Jupyter in the terminal (starting by
> `http://localhost:8889/?token=` or `http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=`).

This snap issue is also mentioned in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238219/618353):

> The Snap ['home'
> interface](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-home-interface/7838)
> permits access only to **non-hidden** files and directories in a
> user's /home.
>
> The Snap ['personal-files'
> interface](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-personal-files-interface/9357)
> permits access to **all** files and directories in a user's /home.
>
> - Snap *interfaces* are defined in the yaml file used in snap creation.
> - The `personal-files` interface requires an additional `$snap connect foo:foo-connect`. The `home` interface does not, which makes it more
>   convenient for some uses.

Also see this relevant thread in the snapcraft forum: [Can browsers open local files?](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/can-browsers-open-local-files/3016)

---

Summarizing, this is probably an issue due to Chromium being a snap application. Your options are:

- Copy and paste one of the links starting with `http://localhost:8889/?token=` or `http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=` in Chromium to open your notebook in it.
- Use another non-snap browser as default.
- Use the [command mentioned by Salvatore Lampitelli](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295138/618353) to open the notebook in the specified non-snap browser.