# Automatically opening Jupyter notebook at http://localhost: instead of file://

Tags: chromium, jupyter

Since Chromium has become a snap package, [it cannot in a standard install access just any files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217639/jupyter-notebook-access-issue-in-chromium).

When launching Jupyter Notebook (executing `jupyter notebook` in a terminal), this directs the default browser to open `file:///home/user/.local/share/jupyter/....html`, which of course fails with Chromium for the reason stated above. This is not a huge deal thanks to Jupyter offering access via `http` as well: `http://localhost:8888/?token=...`.

What I would like is for Jupyter Notebook to forward the `localhost` route to Chromium **automatically**. I cannot find an appropriate [setting in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html). The best I can do is set `c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False` so that I do not have to close the extra tab in Chromium.

Note that, because of *reasons*, I need to use Jupyter Notebook instead of Juptyer Lab, for now.

Comment: How exactly are you launching Jupyter?

Comment: @muru Inside a conda environment, I execute `jupyter notebook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration for Jupyter Notebook, disable `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file`.

To do so, edit `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` and add the following line:

```
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

Note that this option was added as a security measure, [according to the official documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html).